# How to link odometry to a URDF model?

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I have my URDF model and I also am publishing a topic of type nav_msgs::Odometry.  How do I link these together, such that the model moves within Rviz in accordance with the odometry position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9366/how-to-link-odometry-to-a-urdf-model-?/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's where TF comes handy:

A nav_msgs::Odometry is published within a certain frame (field frame_id).
In the same time, your URDF model is also attached to some frame.

To make the robot move according to your odometry, you will need to produce a tf frame that describe where the robot is relative to the world. This transform correspond to the pose field of the odometry message.

Imagine you have a robot which main frame is "base_frame" and you are already producing an odometry message. Just produce a tf frame from "world" to "base_frame" that contains the pose values of your odometry message.

For more information and code example, see [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) tutorial.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-10**:
Ok, I think I've understood.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-09**:
Just as a precision. In my case, the only reason I am publishing a nav_msgs::Odometry message is to make my robot compatible with the navigation stack, which expects odometry information as nav_msgs::Odometry messages (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=overview_tf.png) . Visualization in Rviz is purely based on the TF frames.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-09**:
No. your URDF model only describes the aspect of your robot and is (if I am not wrong) linked to some frames of your robot. All you need to do is to publish a TF transform between the main frame of your robot (base_link in my example) and a frame that represent the reference of your odometry system (world in my example, odom in the tutorial).

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-09**:
Does this mean adding a "world" link and an "odom" joint to the URDF model ?